# Displaying laravel stored images on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, shared-hosting

I have successfully deployed my first laravel application on a live server. Everything looks great except the fact that I am unable to display the images that are being uploaded to the 
`/myproject_src/storage/app/public/myfolder1` folder.

Here is my folder hierarchy on HostGator:

> /myproject_src/

Here are all the laravel source files (except the public folder)

> /public_html/mydomain.com/

Here goes all my contents of the public directory

I am storing the file path into the database in the following manner:

`public/myfolder1/FxEj1V1neYrc7CVUYjlcYZCUf4YnC84Z3cwaMjVX.png`

This path is associated with the image that has been uploaded to storage/app/public/myfolder1/ this folder and is generated from  `store('public/myfolder1');` method of laravel.

What should I do in order to display the images properly in a img tag:

```
<img src="{{ how to point to the uploaded image here }}">
```

Comment: `<img src="{{ storage_path('public/myfolder1/FxEj1V1neYrc7CVUYjlcYZCUf4YnC84Z3cwaMjVX.png') }}">` did you try that?

Comment: @imrealashu that outputs the entire path including my root directory. something like this: `/home3/eisenheim/myproject_src/storage//public/myfolder1/FxEj1V1neYrc7CVUYjlcYZCUf4YnC‌​84Z3cwaMjVX.png`

Comment: Please check my answer I think this would help. I generally do while using it on my shared hosting.

Comment: @imrealashu This worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you can create symbolic link using

```
php artisan storage:link
```

and access files using

```
<img src="{{ asset('public/myfolder1/image.jpg') }}" />
```

But sometime you can't create symbolic link if you're on shared hosting. You want to protect some files behind some access control logic, there is the alternative of having a special route that reads and serves the image. For example.

```
Route::get('storage/{filename}', function ($filename)
{
    $path = storage_path($filename);

    if (!File::exists($path)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
});
```

Now you can access your files like this.

```
http://example.com/storage/public/myfolder1/image.jpg
<img src="{{ asset('storage/public/myfolder1/image.jpg') }} />
```

**Note:** I'd suggest to not store paths in the db for flexibility. Please just store file name and do the following thing in the code.

```
Route::get('storage/{filename}', function ($filename)
{
    // Add folder path here instead of storing in the database.
    $path = storage_path('public/myfolder1' . $filename);

    if (!File::exists($path)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
});
```

and access it using

```
http://example.com/storage/image.jpg
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer here is run `php artisan storage:link` command manually

first, delete the storage folder inside your public folder
then add this code to the top of the web.php file.

```
Artisan::call('storage:link');
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way that works could be running `php artisan storage:link` in your shared hosting ssh terminal. Then simply change the url for the public driver in `filesystem.php`

```
'disks' => [

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
    ]
```