# laravel Asset() function break down after deployment

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, web-deployment, assets

I developeded a Laravel web app, which works fine and great on local machine but
after going in production on a shared hosting server i have some issues displaying the logo and the website images using the asset() helper function.

However the css and js are accessible and works fine (also using the asset function).

I've deployed the App following the steps bellow:

1. I created a directory called repositories outside the public_html (the root document of mydomain.com)  and i copied inside it directory soukelafalah (contining all the files of my laravel project)
2. I moved the laravel public directory files into the public_html directory
3. I edited the index.php in public_html as follow:

   require **DIR**.'./../repositories/SoukElfalah/vendor/autoload.php';
   $app = require_once__DIR__.'/../repositories/SoukElfalah/bootstrap/app.php';
4. I run `php artisan storage:link` and the link is succufully created
5. I had  run also:
   `ln -s /home/dtruxpgw/repositories/SoukElfalah/storage/app/public /home/dtruxpgw/public_html/storage`
6. The route and the css is working fine but the logo and the images are not displayed and shows a 404 error as shown in the image below.

So please, can any one point what i am missing?

And when i put  `asset('/storage/images/thumbs/'.$img_name)}}"` am i pointing to the storage directory in the public_html or in the one in the public folder of my laravel app directory.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Are the image files actually on the server? Or have you just duplicated across the database?Have you ran php artisan storage:link **on the server?**

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43575027/displaying-laravel-stored-images-on-shared-hosting

Comment: @swonder yes the file exists on the server, and yes i run the php artisan storage:link on the server

Comment: Can you check the symlink exists, you can find this in `laravel_directory/public/storage`. Then your files should be in `laravel_directory/public/storage/app/public/images/thumbs` correct? The symbolic link created by the artisan command links to `storage/app/public` so things behind the public directory aren't directly accessible. It seems like you've mis-understood how this works when you ran your symlink above.

Comment: @ChamaraAbeysekara yes i tried that too but same problem

Comment: @swonder actually ay first thing i created a symlink from public_html/stoarge to laravel/public/storage but it didnt work neither