# Image storage link not working in online server in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel application where I upload the images in localhost it's working I use the link the storage directory

```
php artisan storage:link
```

**localhost**

when uploading 1 image with my own controller, the image will store in storage/app/public/posts/file1.jpg, at the same time the image will be stored in root/public/storage/posts/file1.jpg => that works great.

but in an **online server shared hosting** 
it's not working when I upload the image

the image will store in storage/app/public/posts/file1.jpg, **but image not store here** in root/public/storage/posts/file1.jpg =>

Comment: Did you run `php artisan storage:link` again when you uploaded your website?

Comment: after uploading on an online server I didn't do that. and i don't know to run this command in online serve

Comment: If you don't have access to ssh maybe this link can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43575027/displaying-laravel-stored-images-on-shared-hosting

Comment: i do this but same problem

Answer (score 5):

I was having trouble getting the Laravel storage working as it should on my localhost.

Solution:
This is how you solve this problem on your localhost (and maybe your production server).

1. Delete the app/public/storage folder
2. Delete the storage/app/public folder
3. Create a folder called 'public' in the  storage/app/ folder (yeah, the one you just deleted)
4. Run the following artisan command:

```html
php artisan storage:link
```

All done!

The files uploaded via Laravel's Storage::class will now appear in both the 'app/public/storage' and 'storage/app/public' folders.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Artisan::call() method inside your route/controller to execute artisan commands without using the terminal.

`$exitCode = Artisan::call('storage:link', [] );
echo $exitCode; // 0 exit code for no errors.`

Comment: I add this code in the top of my route but the same result

Answer (score 0):

change storage_path settings by public_path

```
'public' => [
  'driver' => 'local',
  'root' => public_path('app/public_html/'),
  'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
  'visibility' => 'public',
],

if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
  $image = $request->file('image');
  $filename = 'page' . '-' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $location = public_path('app/public_html/images/' . $filename);
  Image::make($image)->resize(1200, 600)->save($location);
  if(!empty($page->image)){
    Storage::delete('images/' . $page->image);
  }
  $page->image = $filename;            
}
```

if that does not work, you can try:

`$path = base_path().'/../public_html/images';`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm spamming the answers. This guy posted the same problem and solved it saying this:

> SOLVED Thanks for all your helps, I tried to run php artisan
>   storage:link on my server and I found out that my server has disabled
>   symlink for security reason.
>
> So I have changed all my image uploading functions to upload images in
>   my public folder instead of storage folder and now everything is
>   working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well After spending 5 to 6 hours I got solution here

first, delete the  public/storage  {storage} folder 
Second, put this code in the top of the web.php file

```
Artisan::call('storage:link');
```

this code runs the  `php artisan storage:link` command manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue!
When I had a closer look at the storage folder, i found out that on my local version, I have a link but on the online server it was a regular folder.

**This worked for me on shared host.**
I added the command "`Artisan::call('storage:link', [] );`" to the beginning of the route file and deleted the storage folder from public. It is important to delete the folder, otherwise it did not work for me. Removed the code from the route, when is working, since it should only run once on the server.